# Positinal argument directly in bash for a command

Tags: linux, command-line, bash

No sure if this been asked before, but I want to create and use a positional argument directly in a oneliner.

For instance i use `du -sh` together with a pipe a lot:

```
du -sh /opt/directory/* |sort -h
```

If possible I would like the directory structure for du to be in the end like this:

```
du -sh $1 |sort -h
```

How would I pass in the directory to $1 in the same line as a oneliner?

Comment: (I refer also to your comment from under the answer.) Your first command (`du -sh /opt/directory/* |sort -h`) is a oneliner directly in the terminal. Now you don't want a function that simplifies the way you run things (`dus /opt/directory/*` is simpler, isn't it?) and obviously your first command is also not what you want; thus my impression is you want to *complicate* the way. Is `sh -c 'du -sh "$@" | sort -h' sh /opt/directory/*` what you want? Why? [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/355310)?

Answer (score 0):

Declare a function that does what you want:

```
dus () {
    du -sh "$@" | sort -h
}
```

You can then call it with

```
dus /opt/directory/*
```

To make the declaration permanent, include it to a `.bashrc` or similar file your shell sources when started.

Comment: Yeah, thats unfortunately not what I need. Is is not possible to do without a function or a script? ie - a oneliner directly in the terminal.

Comment: I don't understand. What do you want to abstract from `du -sh /opt/directory/* |sort -h`?